# Changing symlinks does not work for directories

Tags: 10.04, command-line, symbolic-link

In order to change a symbolic link, one can use the -fs option to eliminate the need to unlink or delete the old link first. However, trying to do so on directories does not seem to work:

```
$ mkdir dir1
$ mkdir dir2
$ ln -s  dir1 lnk
$ ln -sf dir2 lnk
$ ll
......... lnk -> dir1
$
```

Why so? Is there another option to do this with directories the same as with files?

Comment: thought about reading the man page of ls?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, if you pass a directory (or a symlink to a directory) as the second argument to the `ln` command, it will create a link inside that directory with the same name as the first argument.  So with the set of commands you have issued, you should find a symlink named `dir2` inside `dir1`.

You can change this behaviour using the `-T` option:

```
-T, --no-target-directory
       treat LINK_NAME as a normal file
```

If you pass this option in your second `ln` invocation, then it should overwrite the `lnk` symlink rather than creating a new symlink inside the first directory.

Comment: Definitely does the job.